# Is there English geolocation data in Big Query's public dataset for GeoLite by Maxmind?

Tags: google-bigquery, maxmind, geolite2

When querying the geolite public dataset in Big Query [found here](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=geolite2&page=dataset&_ga=2.90521308.-715981635.1500777023&_gac=1.215576293.1578718839.CjwKCAiA3uDwBRBFEiwA1VsajOL6i9cgIFTTfNM3z4FzKLLJKLOqiqolKdjFOZWdf6kb21T-KRBwvBoCppEQAvD_BwE&project=podcast-223814&folder&organizationId), the results are for the 'es' locale. Is there 'en' locale data available in the public dataset or do we need to manually download the english data from Maxmind and insert it to our own Big Query datasets? I was hoping this data was maintained by Big Query public dataset owner.

*Sample query:*

```sql
SELECT * FROM 'bigquery-public-data.geolite2.ipv4_city_locations' WHERE city_name = 'Vancouver';
```

*Result:*

[image: Query Result]

For more context: [Big Query and Geolocation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no table with `en` locale in geolite Bigquery [public datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data).

The best solution would be placing english data in BigQuery manually. Firstly, please download `.zip` file at [Maxmind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geoip2-city-country-csv-databases/), which contains a single directory with 13 files. Eight CSV files contains data location for each locale code, where `locale` can be `de`, `en`, `es`, `fr`, `ja`, `pt-BR`, `ru`, and `zh-CN`. You should see csv similar to this one: `GeoLite2-{Content}-Locations-en.csv`.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Answer (score 0):

I filed an issue to get this fixed. Track it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149249389.

In the meantime, use my tables. This one only encodes for 'en':

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_locations_en`  
WHERE city_name = 'Vancouver'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Felipe, are those public geoip data sets updated regularly?

Comment: They should be, and if they're not - a issue request like the one above should help